# How to make margin right work for span element?

Tags: css, margin, html

I have a span element which I want to be present at teh right corner of the page. For that I have used `margin-right:10px`. But it shows no effect. Where as `margin-left` works. Why is this? And how to make the span element appear at the right side of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin-right is the right margin.

If you want to align it to the right you can use right:10px that is if position is absolute.

otherwise you can use float:right

You can also set the display:inline-block to the span.

You can learn more about margins 
http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html
http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/margins/

Comment: Because its already aligned to the left corner, so when you set margin-left its clearly visible to you. The margin-right also works when you set it but because its not aligned to right you dont see the effect.

Answer (score 5):

Try this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXVKP/))

```
.right-corner {
    float:right;
}
```

or this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PJpyj/))

```
.right-corner {
    position:absolute:
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

The reason that margin-right doesn't work is because it's just giving your element a right margin not repositioning it. To help you understand, if you put something after your element with `margin-right` there will be a gap between them which is the margin.

`margin-left` does this as well, it's just doing it on the left side and since elements are places from left-to-right there is the gap on the left side which looks like it just shifted to the right.

Have a look at [this little example](http://jsfiddle.net/GBYg9/) to try to understand. You should read up on the [CSS box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) if you don't understand.

[image: CSS box model, from www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is float:right;

Answer (score 1):

In order to complete @Tyriar answer, here's a fiddle also showing you the use of **`text-align: right`**. And why a margin can exist but have no observable effect. Also how to use the `clear` property after a floating element and/or a clearfix on containers of floating elements (both are not necessary here)

http://jsfiddle.net/rLQbk/

One more advice: do NOT use absolute positioning if you're not really (really) sure of what you want to achieve and how; most of the time it's not the best solution to a CSS problem. Completely out of the flow, its content will display over other content without any care...

Comment: The parent controls the horizontal alignment of its content. `img` itself has no content so yes it's void afaik and aligning its parent will align the image (or the text replacement if for any reason the image can't be displayed)